# return the name of the row(first column) of the maximum difference between two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this :

```
  Country   1990  1995 2000 2005 2010  2015
0   Bahrain     5     4    3    2   1    20
1   Maldives   10     9    8    7   6    30
2   Germany    7      4    3    2   1    40
.      ....     ..    ..   ..    ..  ..  ..
.      ....     ..    ..   ..    ..  ..  ..
.      ....     ..    ..   ..    ..  ..  ..
```

I want to calculate the difference between column 2015 and 1990 and then return the name of the row with the maximum difference.
In this case is Germany.

I wrote this:

```py
highest_growth =(df['2020']-df['1990']).abs().idxmax()
```

which returns the index of the country with the maximum difference but I want to have the name of the country as a string output.
I don't want an extra column.Just returning the name of the country with the max value of df['2020']-df['1990'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the index of the row, you can get the country name by indexing `df['Country']`:

```
highest_growth_index = (df['2020']-df['1990']).abs().idxmax()
highest_growth = df['Country'][highest_growth_index]
```

In one line:

```
highest_growth = df['Country'][(df['2020']-df['1990']).abs().idxmax()]
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working. I wonder if there is a way I can get the name with one line of code.

Comment: you can combine them, see my edit

Answer (score 2):

Sort by highest growth, then select the last row and get the country name:

```
df["highest_growth"] = df["2015"] - df["1990"]
highest_growth = df.sort_values("highest_growth").iloc[-1]["Country"]
```

Result:

```
Germany
```